# GetHostAddress() returns no IPv6, only IPv4

Tags: c#, dns, ipv6

When using Dns.GetHostAddresses("fred") it returns only IPv4 addresses in response. How to get the IPv6 addresses as well? Is there different method I shall use?

Socket.OSSupportsIPv6 returns true and IPv6 connections work fine. The OS is Windows 2008 R2, .Net version is 3.5.

Comment: Does "fred" have an IPv6 DNS record associated with it?

Comment: @Lazarus: No, I didn't - I've added the entry to hosts file and I now got the both ipv4 and ipv6 addresses resolved! How do I know if there are dns records associated with the hostname? Why did "ping -6 fred" work fine, while GetHostAddresses() did not?

Comment: @ya23 I would suspect that ping will drop back to an IPv4 lookup when it can't resolve the IPv6.

Comment: Windows may have been doing some sneaky LLMNR behind your back. Always use DNS.

Comment: @Lazarus, @ Jeremy Visser: Adding the DNS record has fixed the problem. Please post that as an answer, so I can accept that. Would be great if you could also explain why ping was so misleading - it was resolving the hostname just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPv6 still uses DNS to resolve addresses so in order for this to work you will need to add an IPv6 entry to your zone file for this domain name. It'll then resolve properly.

I suspect that Ping will fall back to IPv4 if an IPv6 is not available, not exactly what you'd hope once you've specified the '-6' flag.

Comment: This is not what I'm seeing. If I query in node.js using `dns.lookup('google.com',{all:true}, ...)` I get both an ipv6 and ipv4 address  where as in C# with `Dns.GetHostAddresses("google.com")` no ipv6 address is returned on the same machine.

Comment: GetHostAddresses will filter IPv6 addresses if IPv6 is not installed on the system. Given that Google isn't on your local network you may be getting an IPv4 that's mapped to the IPv6. Do you have end to end IPv6 between yourself and Google? I'm assuming here that the node.js and .Net execution system is the same and if not that both are configured for the same DNS resolution chain.

Comment: [Here's the example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37386839/both-dns-gethostaddress-and-dns-gethostentry-return-only-ipv4-addresss-how-do-i). Maybe I'm doing something stupid

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still having this problem in 2021, the `System.Net.Dns` class has an undocumented behavior: **it filters addresses it thinks are unreachable** when your only IPv6 address besides loopback is [link-local](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address#IPv6). This filtering is performed even if the domain name exclusively resolves to a v6 address (you can try with `v6.localhost.ayra.ch`), in which case an exception is thrown.

If you're located in an IPv4 only network but want the ability to resolve v6 addresses in .NET, you can cheat your way around this problem by manually assigning your device a custom IP. Assign your device the IPv6 address `2001:db8::1` with a prefix length of `32` and no default gateway. I haven't found anything that stopped working so far because of this, and .NET will now resolve IPv6.

Note that the suggested IPv6 address and range is reserved for use in documentations, which means you should never encounter this range on the internet at all. If you want to make sure your choice doesn't conflicts with the address of someone else that follows this instruction, I suggest you use your mac address for the last 3 address segments.

I made a page that generates these address either with your MAC or randomly: https://cable.ayra.ch/docmac/